# File transfer rate over Java socket

Tags: sockets, file-transfer, sametime

I have implemented simple Java sockets for file transfer over WiFi channel. The file transfer rate never goes beyond 3.2 Mbps. I was wondering how Lotus Sametime works? We use this software for internal communications in our office, like simple chat and file transfers. Sametime is incredibly fast even over normal WiFi connection. Not even applications like Airdroid has that kind of file transfer performance. How does Sametime transfers files with such high speed? Maybe I could use the same technique in my Java application for file transfer. Any help please?

Comment: One thing that come to my mind, and that I use, is compress the data. ZIP method or any other compression method. Sometimes you get 80% smaller, depending on the kind of data that you are sending. Don't use it in JPG, GIF o PNG images data, you waste your time.

Comment: This is not a practical solution. Compression itself takes a lot of time, especially if you have a lot of smaller files that you want to put in single archive. Lotus Sametime doesn't use compression before sending either! I wanted to know, how Sametime achieves such astonishing data transfer rate.

Comment: Then, we need to see your code, how you send and received the data, maybe there is something wrong in it. Otherwise, can't imagine how Sametime speed it up. About the compression time it must be measured and how you do it. A thread could be compressing while other thread is sending what have been compressed, and the same at the other side. Depends how you do it. The CPU is much faster than the LAN traffic